# How to code R language when connecting to a large dataset in BigQuery

Tags: r, google-bigquery, database-connection

I want to use R code instead of SQL or DBI to program off the BigQuery connection without downloading the table.

I want to use R code instead of SQL or DBI to program. Currently I am connected to BigQuery and the table I'm using is too large to download. I am wondering if there is a way to query using R code off the database. 
The Google searches I have tried only shows how to query using SQL and DBI (within R) but I want to use the R language.
Is there a way to do this in R just like using SQL in BigQuery or SAS?

I do not want to use codes such as:

```
sql_query <-
"SELECT x,sum(y) FROM `table1`;"
```

OR

```
x <- y %>% group_by(z) %>% summarise(
w = sum(a + b,
na.rm = TRUE)
```

Comment: You can't use R in the BigQuery UI, no. You can however work with BigQuery via R Studio or a notebook, see this blog post: https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/google-cloud-platform-for-data-scientists-using-r-with-google-bigquery and these docs for notebooks: https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/notebooks/docs/use-r-bigquery

Comment: Can you query the table in chunks (years, months, some other split) in R and save each result to file?  This keeps dataset footprint a bit smaller.  Then however you are manipulating your files, you just loop through them and do the same thing to each.

Comment: @Ben P could you please post your comment as an answer for the benefit of the community?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use R in the BigQuery UI, no.

You can however work with BigQuery via R Studio or a notebook, see this blog post: https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/google-cloud-platform-for-data-scientists-using-r-with-google-bigquery

And these docs for notebooks: 
https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/notebooks/docs/use-r-bigquery